# "Passing variable value dynamically in xmllint xmlpath command in shellscript"

Tags: shell

I would like to pass the variable `$sname`'s value in the below statement

```
sname="xyz"
snames_arry=$(xmllint --xpath 
'(//source[@name="$sname"]/files/file_names/text())' source.xml)
```

but it's not taking the value of `$source_name`.
The error is XPath set is empty because it can't resolve the value of `$source_name`.
Hard coding the value of `$sname` works, but I want to make it dynamic.
Can anybody please help me with the above issue?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: The source code that you share does not have reference to '$source_name'. Do you mean '$sname' ?

Comment: hi dash, Its sname not source_name my mistake regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell does not perform variable substitution on strings in single quote. Consider using double quote

```
sname="xyz"
snames_arry=$(xmllint --xpath  "(//source[@name="$sname"]/files/file_names/text())" source.xml)
```

Comment: In that case you can accept the answer (or mine). This answer might fail when `$sname` has spaces (the double quotes around the variable get lost).

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

No substution is done between single quotes.
Single quotes can be stopped and started like

```
# examples
    echo 'Hel'lo 'world'
    echo '($LOGIN, $USER)=("'$LOGIN'", "'$USER'").'
```

In your case:

```
snames_arry=$(xmllint --xpath 
'(//source[@name="'$sname'"]/files/file_names/text())' source.xml)
```